# How to filter and exclude files from gci?

Tags: powershell

I am using the following:

```
Get-ChildItem $CSV_Files_Path -Filter *.csv | foreach-object {...}
```

There is one specific csv file however i wish to exclude. sure i can move it from that directory, but i'd have to do that everytime its replaced so i would like this to be dynamic...

I know that we cannot combine exclude with filter, so how can i accomplish this?

pseudocode:

```
Get-ChildItem $CSV_Files_Path -Filter *.csv -Exclude Fact.csv | foreach-object {...}
```

even better, i'd like to take this further with user input file exclusion.

i.e. `param($excludedfiles)`

```
$excludedfiles = 'C:\CSVFiles\Fact.csv, C:\CSVFiles\fileabc.csv'
```

or even as flexible as:

```
$excludedfiles = 'Fact.csv, fileabc.csv'
```

pseudocode:

```
$excludedfiles = $excludedfiles.Split('(.+?)(?:,|$)')
Get-ChildItem $CSV_Files_Path -Filter *.csv -Exclude $excludedfiles | foreach-object {...}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot of annoying things with -filter, -include, and -exclude in powershell 5.  It's resolved in newer versions.  You could combine -path and -exclude:

```
get-childitem -path *.csv -exclude file1.csv,file2.csv
```

Comment: i agree its quite annoying why certain things are the way they are in certain powershell versions...btw, this one displays any file type, not just csv...how can i specify the csv portion for it? i know file* is for recursion to use with exclude, but it still fetches everything else regardless if its csv or not :/

Comment: i just figured it out before you answered back lol, `get-childitem -path .\*.csv* -exclude file1.csv,file2.csv` thanks though!